# How to ensure that my new Windows 10 bootable drive will be named C:?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning

I have an ASUS laptop with the following according to Disk Management:

- Disk 0: 2.5" 1TB hard drive, one partition is C: and contains Windows 10
- Disk 1: 16GB m.2 SSD, one partition and named D:

I have successfully replaced the SSD with a 500GB m.2 SSD.  It is still D: and is fully accessible.

I now want to clean install Windows 10 onto the SSD, and basically use the 1TB just for data. If I do it without removing the 1TB physically out of the computer, will Windows now rename the SSD as C: or is there a way to ensure that the SSD becomes C: with the bootable Windows?  (I am not interested or want multi-boot.)

If instead I remove the 1TB drive physically and install Windows onto the SSD, will the SSD now become C: by default?

Comment: Yes, the SSD will now be C:\ by default

Comment: Are you referring only to the second method, ie I remove the 1TB drive physically from the computer?

Comment: You can boot into the SSD without disconnecting the HDD. Boot by selecting the SSD in the BIOS boot menu.